# pass an object from sinkconnector to sinktask in kafka connect

Tags: java, apache-kafka-connect

i'm trying to pass an object from my sinkconnector to my sinktask. I can't find anything in the documentation. the only method where they use to share something is in connector.taskConfigs and task.start, but that's just for Map, and i need to pass an object from another class.

does anyone has any ideas or know how this can be done?

thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kafka Connect does not currently have a general-purpose way to pass an object from any `Connector` implementation to its `Task` implementations. This is actually by design because the tasks may be instantiated in a different worker than where the connector was instantiated. The only information passed from a `Connector` instance to the `Task` object is via the task configuration.

If you're willing to only run the connector in Kafka Connect's standalone process or *only* in a distributed worker cluster *with exactly one worker*, then you can use a static object since the `Connector` and `Task` implementations will always be instantiated in the same process (assuming they come from the same plugin). However, this is obviously brittle and will not work for general-purpose connectors.

Comment: i think that using that static object approach is too risky, i will redesign my plugin to not need this.

thanks for the idea and the explanation! :)